# Passing two values from Ajax to a Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to pass the value of TransactionNumber into the controller but I am getting an undefined result.

here is my code,

```
function getall()
{
$('#tbl-transaction').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$('#tbl-transaction').DataTable({

               "ajax": {
    
                   "url": '/Admin/GetAllTransactions',
                   "type": "get",
                   "datatype" : "JSON"
    
               },
    
               "columns" :
                   [
    
                       { data :"TransactionNumber"},
                       { data: "PurposeOfVisit" },
                       { data: "NameOfHostFromST" },
                       { data: "TransactedBy" },
                        {
                            data: "id", "render" : function(data)
                            {
                                return '<button class= "btn btn-success" onclick = "get_details(' + data+ ')"> Details </button>';
                            }
                        }
                   ]
    
           })
    
       }
    
       function get_details(id,TransactionNumber)
       {
           window.location.href = '/Approver/Details/' + id + '?=' + TransactionNumber;
       }
```

controller side

```
public ActionResult Details(int Id, string TN)
        {
            tbl_FSEWeb_Transaction tbl_FSEWeb_Transaction = db.tbl_FSEWeb_Transaction.Find(Id);
            //var course = 0;
            return View(tbl_FSEWeb_Transaction);
        }
```

I'm using ASP.net mvc and ajax.

Comment: Could you show your controller code, related to this action?

Comment: @DShadrin, i edited my question to include my controller code

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your URL is incorrect. Replace your javascript function with:

```
window.location.href = '/Approver/Details/?id=' + id + '&tn=' + TransactionNumber;
```

The initial parameters follow the format:

```
?<name>=<value>
```

Multiple parameters are then added with ampersands (&)

Comment: Thank you for the help, yes I am getting the value of the id but TransactionNumber is still undefined/null during get_details(id,TransactionNumber)

Comment: @bran.tyler Try calling the controller method manually via a URL, e.g: https://localhost:44391/Approver/Details?id=123&tn=456 - and see if this hits your controller method with both parameters. If this succeeds, then we know your problem lies with the data passed to the javascript method, and not your controller method.

Comment: thank you! I just realized that the problem lies with passing data on TransactionNumber to function get_details(). With regards to that, how can I pass the data of TN from getall() to  get_details()?

Comment: @bran.tyler It is most likely the format of the 'data' attribute being passed to the function in your dynamic button's onclick event. I would try logging that 'data' variable to console to see if it's in the expected format. Unfortunately this looks like an issue with jquery Datatable formatting which I am unfamiliar with - I would suggest updating your question tags to include 'Datatable'.